# Show that the Trace of a function of matrix converge

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, matrix-calculus, trace

Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a square matrix of dimension $N$ with zeros on the diagonal. I assume that the entries of $\mathbf{G}$ are in the interval $[0, 1$] and $\displaystyle \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{j = 1}^N\mathbf{G}_{ij} = 1$.

I want to prove that
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbf{Trace}\left((\mathbf{I} - \alpha \mathbf{G})^{-1}\mathbf{G}\right) < \infty,$$ for any $\alpha$ in $(0, 1)$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix of dimension $N$.

This is also equivalent to prove that

$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbf{Trace}\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \alpha^k\mathbf{G}^{k + 1}\right) < \infty.$$

Comment: Since tr(A+B)=tr(A)+tr(B), your last condition amounts to requiring that $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \alpha^k \operatorname{tr}(G^{k+1})<\infty$$
So establishing some useful bounds on traces of $G^{k+1}$ seems like a good start.

Comment: Thanks @Semiclassical. I agree. This is what I tried to do. But it seems a bit tricky

Comment: what does 'smallest' eigenvalue mean?  $\mu_{max}$ can be taken to be real as the Perron root (evidently $\in (0,1)$), but a 'minimum doesn't make any sense as stated, doubly so for an interval $(-1/\mu_{\min}, 1/\mu_{\max})$.

Comment: @user8675309, For a matrix defined in this way, All the eigenvalues are real because all the entries on the diagonal are 0. Or this is true from some $N$ due to the boundness of $\sum_{j=1}^N\mathbf{G}_{ij}$

Comment: *"All the eigenvalues are real because all the entries on the diagonal are 0."*  That is not a theorem.  Consider a non-involutary permutation matrix that is traceless.  Contradiction.

Comment: @user8675309 All the diagonal entries are not 0. May be I do not understand your point.

Comment: *"All the diagonal entries are not 0"*.  Your post is specifically about a sophisticated use of the trace of a matrix.  You really should be able to figure out what it means for a permutation matrix to be traceless.

Comment: I modify the post. $G$ is now defined as a adjacency matrix (as in spatial econometric). I also make it more simple. $\alpha \in (0, 1)$.